# How can I replace this condition by a probability?

Tags: probability, clustering, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, distance-functions

I want to see if a datapoint x should (or not) be assigned to a nearest component y using the following condition:

if ($d > T$) then {do not assign x to y}. With $d = distance(x,y)$ and $T = \bar{d}+\sigma$ where $\bar{d}$ is the mean distance of y to datapoints that were already assigned to it in the past, and $\sigma$ the associated stdev.

I want to replace this condition (i.e. ($d > T$)) by an equivalent expression which is expressed as a probability $p$. How can I do that ? I've tried for exemple $p = exp(\frac{-d^2}{2\sigma`^2}) / (\sigma`\sqrt{2\pi})$ but it does not behave like the first condition unless we manually find a good value for $\sigma`$

Note: it does not really matter if it is not a true probability (that sum to one).

Comment: If you have any parameters at all in your probability calculation, they are going to have to be tuned somehow if you want good results, and if you don't have any parameters, you're not likely to get good results, except by great luck.  Also, any probability calculation will have to take into account all the distances, otherwise you can't ensure the probabilities sum to one (note that even "set p=1 for the minimum distance component" takes all the distances into account when calculating the minimum.)

Comment: @jbowman please be more clear, are you saying that I should keep $\sigma`$ and vary it manually (by increasing it) until I get a satisfying results ?! Note that the first condition works well, I just want to replace it with an equivalent probabilistic expression.

Comment: Note that exp(−d$^2$/2σ`$^2$) is not a probability.  You need to normalize by dividing it by (√2π)σ`.

Comment: @MichaelChernick this does not matter since we manually change $\sigma`$ until it behaves like the first condition. I don't know however if there is any way to "learn" the good value for $\sigma`$

Comment: What you have is only proportional to a probability density.  It is not the normal probability density without the normalization. In any case the terminology is wrong.  You were attempting to express the requirement in terms of the height of the probability density and not in terms of a probability.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Well ok let's normalize on $(\sigma`\sqrt{2\pi})$, this does not change the fact that we still need to find the value of $\sigma`$ that makes this probability behaves like the first condition ($d < T$). I heard about maximum likelihood, but I don't know what is it exactly and if it is convenient for this problem ?

Comment: Maximizing the likelihood would look for parameter values for the parameters that define the probability density for the distance between x and y to be highest.  But what you want hear is to find a d so the the density is relatively low beyond that d.  So you would want to choose T so that the tail probability P(d>T)<a  where a is a small number like 0.05.  To get this you would compute the intgral of the density for d>T for various values of T until that integral gets smaller than a.

Comment: @MichaelChernick is this equivalent to computing the integral of P which is defined as ($P = exp(\frac{-d^2}{2\sigma`^2}) / (\sigma`\sqrt{2\pi})$) for d > T, and repeat this for various values of $sigma`$ until that integral gets smaller than a=0.05 ? Then I can say this is the good value for $sigma`$ ?

Comment: @user995434 I suppose you could do that if somehow you already know the right value of T and want to see what sigma makes that probability sufficiently small.  But originally T was defined in terms of sigma.  If you want to maintain the definition of T as average d + sigma  you could change sigma and be changing T at the same time until you got the sigma that satisfied your conditions.

Comment: @MichaelChernick note that here $\sigma$ is totally different from $\sigma`$. And what do you mean by "until you got the value that **satisfied your conditions**" ? Do you mean that for each new d higher than T, I compute the probability P, and see if it is higher than 0.05 then I increase T and do P = P + Previous_P (discrete integration for values of d > T) ?

Comment: @user995434 Why are the sigmas different.  Id T= avg. d + sigma and you increase sigma leaving avg d fixed P(d>T) gets smaller and at the same time the density you are integrating is getting smaller.

Comment: @MichaelChernick but $\bar{d}$ and $\sigma$ will change each time a new datapoint x is assigned to y, does this matter ? And how do we increase $\sigma$ since it changes when a new x is assigned to y ?

Comment: @user995434 p is a probability density function. You take its integral for a d greater than T after you pick sigma.  If the integral is too large increase sigma and thus increase T repat the integration.  Once the integral gets small enough you have the sigma you want.

Comment: The threshold T is fixed.  You determine it through the integration and apply the same T to every new data point unless for some reason you think there is some change to your model that requires a reevaluation of sigma.

Comment: @MichaelChernick The threshold T is local to each component y (normally I should write $T_y$ instead), and it is not fixed since it depends on "the mean distance ($\bar{d}$)" of y to data points that were already assigned to it (this mean that each time a new datapoint x is assigned to y, its associated $\bar{d}$ will be updated) ! I understand that we can compute a "good" sigma (or say $\sigma_y$) for a given component y through the integration P(d > $T_y$), but is it possible when the $\bar{d}$ associated to this y is not fix ?

Comment: In the integral you have removed mu from the equation.  So the only effect on the integral will come from sigma.  A small change in sigma may not make the change in the integral very noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

If y is too far from x you should be able to define T independent of y. I wouldn't do it this way.  But if you want to update sigma and T and then calculate P(d>T) you can and decide whether or not to keep y based on that probability.